# How to reformat hdd only viewable under (About Mac) -> (System Report) -> (USB 3.0 Bus)?

Tags: time-machine, disk-utility, usb, external-disk

After changing to a new external USB hdd for *Time Machine* my previous external USB drive used for *Time Machine* (almost) disappeared. My old drive is a *Western Digital, My Passport 25E3 for Mac* (1-tb). It is **not** recognized in:

- Disk Utility
- (About This Mac) --> (Storage)
- **/Volumes$**ls -l

However, I can see the old *Time Machine* drive here: (*About This Mac*) --> (*System Report*) --> (*USB*) --> (*USB 3.0 Bus*) -> **My Passport 25E3**

What can I do to reformat that old *Time Machine* drive and mount it as just a normal external drive? I've rebooted several times and used different cables.

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

The problem was that disk had an **EFI System Partition**. All the work to make the disk readable for *MacOS El Capitan* was done on *Windows 10*.
**C:\Temp>** *diskpart*
**DISKPART>**  *select disk 1*
**--->** *clean*
**DISKPART>**  *exit*

note:
(I just noticed that Mac has */usr/sbin/diskutil* that I'm sure would have allowed me to deal with the EFI Partition.)

So, I used the Windows Disk Utility to create a 1-tb xFAT partition. MacOS recognized that. Then, I reformatted that to MacOS file format, 1-tb partition. perfect.

As can be seen in the question, MacOS only recognized that disk in 1 place, in the USB device tree. Only Windows seems to have allowed me to see that EFI System Partition and then allowed me to manipulate the disk.